# How to use a Semantic Tableau to show satisfiable and falsifiable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability, beth-tableau

I'm working on using semantic tableau to prove properties of formulas. I've got the hang of building them, but there's some theory I'm unsure of.

I'm aware that to a formula can be proven unsatisfiable if all branches are closed.

I'm also aware that a formula can be proven valid if the negation of that formula is proven unsatisfiable like done so above.

But how can I prove that a formula is both satisfiable and falsifiable?

I'm sure it can be done by proving that a formula is not unsatisfiable and not valid. But is there a shorter way? Or is it common practice to prove the formula to be both not unsatisfiable and not valid?

Comment: I don't know if there's a method for determining satisfiability + invalidity in one sweep, but I've always tested for them separately.

Comment: Thanks for that comment :) It gives me more validation that I was on the right track :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed done by two trees: one where $\phi$ leads to at least one open and finished branch (showing satisfiablity of $\phi$), and one where $\neg \phi$ leads to at least one open and finished branch (showing falsifiablity of $\phi$)

Comment: Thank you, that clarity is just what I needed :)

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Note that in the general case, indeed two trees are required: A first intuition might be that to check for contingency, it suffices to verify that the tableau has at least one open and one closed branch; but the limit case of atomic formulas (which are contingent -- they can be true or false) shows that we won't catch all contingent formulas that way: A tableau for an atomic formula will have just one branch, which will remain open, but no closed branch. The same will hold for the negated atomic formula, so only the combination of these shows the contingency of the formula.

Comment: @lemontree Even if a tree has at least one open and at least one closed branch, that does not mean it is a contingency. Consider $(P \lor \neg P) \lor (Q \land \neg Q)$.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Thanks for pointing it out.